# Reduced Sample Space in Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The dice game craps is played as follows: The player throws $2$ dice, and if the sum is 7 or 11, he/she wins. If the sum is 2, 3, or 12, he/she loses. If the sum is anything else (a point), he/she continues throwing until that point appears again or throws a 7, where the game ends in a loss.

It is easy to formulate the probability of winning or losing in the first throw; what confuses me is how to proceed. The solution mentions the *method of reduced sample spaces*.

For example, if 4 is our point, there are $3$ ways to make the point and $6$ ways to get a $7$. So the probability of getting a point is $3/3+6$. Why are we ignoring the other outcomes of the dice throw?

What is the intuition behind reduced sample spaces? And when can we apply it?

Comment: We are considering only the toss results that have a consequence. Other than a point and a $7$, other results don't matter, "the method of reduced sample spaces."